# (VBA) Can't check if file exists because Dir is case-sensitive

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I'm writing a program which writes links into an excel sheet based on various data found in the sheet. My company used SOLIDWORKS PDM to store files, so I'm using the PDM API (the pdmv object) to write the links. Some of the files don't exist due to faulty data, so I need some kind of error checking before referencing the pdmv object and writing the link.

The issue I'm running into is with case-sensitive file locations. `GetFolderFromPath` and `GetFile` commands are case-insensitive, so the program writes links without problems if they exist. However, since the `Dir` command is case-sensitive, I can't properly check if the files exist before running the link-writing commands.

Is there any way to use `Dir` without worrying about case, or is there a different, case-insensitive method to checking if a file exists that might work here?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
evidently, `Dir` is case-insensitive, so the issue must be arising from the server that my company uses to store files, SOLIDWORKS PDM. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue, so any ideas are welcome.

```
Sub writeLink(link As String, palRow As Long, asArray, pdmv As Object)
    Dim textDisp As String
    textDisp = asArray(1) & "-" & asArray(2) & "-1000"
    
    Dim filename As String
    filename = textDisp & ".sldasm"
    
    testVar = Dir(link & "\" & filename)
    
    If Not testVar = "" Then
        
        Dim efolder As Object
        Dim efile As Object
        
        Set efolder = pdmv.GetFolderFromPath(link)
        Set efile = efolder.GetFile(filename)
        
        fileLink = "conisio://myvault/explore?projectid=" & efolder.id & "&documentid=" & efile.id & "&objecttype=1"
        
        calc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=calc.Cells(palRow, 8), _
        Address:=fileLink, _
        TextToDisplay:=textDisp
    Else
        calc.Cells(palRow, 2).Interior.Color = 65535
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dir` isn't case-sensitive.

Comment: What makes you think that `Dir` is case sensitive?

Comment: Since windows filenames are not case sensitive, `Dir` cannot be case sensitive.

Comment: When running the code, Dir returns null for file paths that don't match case perfectly

Comment: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: I am not. any other explanation that might cause this issue?

Comment: For fun, put a breakpoint on the `If Not testVar...` line, execute to that point. Do `?testVar` in the `Immediate` window. Copy the results and paste into the Windows "run" command line. Does it open the file as expected? If not, the path\file name doesn't exist. Work your way through the path\file looking to see where it's broken.

Comment: Also, I'm sure you're aware that `asArray` is defaulting to a `Variant`, with all the inherent issues surrounding that. For cleanlieness of code, I'd also suggest changing `If Not testVar = ""` to `if testVar = ""` and swapping the order of the `if`/`else` - it's just easier (IMHO) to read a _positive_ test condition than a _negative_ one (even though you'd expect the negative to be the most frequently chosen option).

Comment: Printing testVar outputs the file name only, not the entire path. Points taken, regarding the second comment.

Comment: Is the `link` string more like `K:\Some\Folder` or more like `\\SomeServer\Some\Folder`? And have you considered or tried using [`FileSystemObject.FileExists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//x23stk5t(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead?

Comment: An example of what a problem `link` argument looks like would be useful here.

Comment: Related: https://www.inflow-tech.com/blog/2019/01/pdm-search-from-the-command-line/